# Converting column to sub-row using css only

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Im using a table in wordpress site, but I was unable to find its actual php code which is generating that table. So, all I have is table at front end to be edited with only css. I have removed some columns using CSS (can be seen css code on left side of screenshot). What I need is the move the every column cell "More Info" to the beneath under the every row (as indicated by red arrows in screenshot). How CSS can do this? Thanks
Table Link: https://skdstore.com/product/educational-videos-volume-1/

[Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVJQo.png)

Comment: link to site table: https://skdstore.com/product/educational-videos-volume-1/

Comment: You have a couple of options: Either 1) Mark up a new table; 2) Style your data using CSS Tables; 3) Style your data using CSS Grid. I'm barely familiar with WordPress (I've probably used it about 6 times ever) but there must be a search tool to help you find bits of code, is there?

Comment: I tried a lot, by help of two experts, that table was not found. One told that it is written in encrypted js somewhere so no trace. We only have this way to edit by css on front-end

Comment: I'd probably `display: none` the existing table and put together a new table using options 1), 2) or 3).